# what is default balancing window in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have read about balancing window in MongoDB document. I see mongo tell about how to modify balancing window but I don't see the default of balancing window. I see only one document about chunk size in collection settings in config database. Do you know the default of balancing window ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default balancing window is 24x7x365, which means balancer will always move chunks if its on

Comment: technically it will always be on, but it will only move chunks if there is an imbalance

Comment: @AdamC Thanks, this is what i meant but you make it clear